# ListBox items are clickable but not visible WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, visible, clickable

I'm making a Windows Phone 7 app.
I have string items being added to a ListBox.
When I run the app, the items in the ListBox are clickable, but I cannot actually see them.
They are set to visible and white (black background).

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Here is my ListBox code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" ShowGridLines="False">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="i" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="informationButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" FontFamily="Georgia" DataContext="{Binding}" Click="informationButton_Click" />
                <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Name="searchBox1" Text="Search..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="336" TextChanged="searchBox1_TextChanged" />
                <Button Content="→" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-15,0,0,0" Name="searchButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" Click="button1_Click_1"  />                
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox Height="533" Name="listBox" Width="452" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" DoubleTap="textBlock_DoubleTap" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" Padding="2,5">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Height="30" Text="" Margin="2,10" Name="textBlock1" DoubleTap="TextBlock_DoubleTap" Visibility="Visible"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the XAML where the items are added. The string part works.

```
try
{
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.ClassNumber != null) 
        text = text + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.ClassNumber;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.SectionNumber != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.SectionNumber;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.CourseDescr != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.CourseDescr;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.SectionTypeDescr != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.SectionTypeDescr;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Meeting.Days != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Meeting.Days;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Meeting.Times != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Meeting.Times;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Instructor.InstructorName != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.Instructor.InstructorName;
    if (root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.EnrollmentStatus != null) 
        text = text + "   " + root2.getSOCSectionListByNbrResponse.ClassOffered.EnrollmentStatus;
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}

listBox.Items.Add(text);
```

Comment: Show Some code please

Comment: Do you expect to see each text appended in each item? or are you doing a for around this?

Comment: There's a large for around this that includes a new API call for each iteration. So all of the text is one item, and will change each time. When I click on the invisible links, it navigates with the correct information.

Comment: Please try what i have posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through the code you posted and I found the solution:

Replace this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Height="30" Text="" Margin="2,10" Name="textBlock1" DoubleTap="TextBlock_DoubleTap" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

with this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock 
        Height="30" Text="{Binding}" Margin="2,10" 
        Name="textBlock1" DoubleTap="TextBlock_DoubleTap" 
        Visibility="Visible"/>
</DataTemplate>
```